# SP 2010 Service Pack 2 - The trial period for this product has expired

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, configuration, licensing, search-configuration

Brand new 2010 SP 2 install.  Entered Enterprise key, successfully went through config wizard.  I configured a couple of different web apps with team sites and both of them give me `The trial period for this product has expired.` when you browse to them.  I have successfully used this VL SP 2010 Enterprise key before.

Central admin works..

Under Convert Farm License Type, there is no information under Current License, where on a working farm it says `SharePoint Server with Enterprise Client Access License`

Under Manage Patch Status, it says `Not Configured` under Product.

Also, Enable Enterprise Features is missing.

The ULS logs say the following:

```
DelegateControl: Exception thrown while adding control 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SearchBoxEx': Thread was being aborted.
```

When I try to configure search, it errors out with:

```
Errors were encountered during the configuration of the Search Service Application. 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: Session at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.LocationFactory.AddLocationConfiguration(LocationConfigurationCollection LocationCollection, String InternalName, String DisplayName, String AdminDescription, LocationType Type, String ConnectionUrlTemplate, String MoreLinkTemplate, Visualization SummaryVisualization, Visualization FullVisualization, Visualization TopAnswerVisualization, AuthenticationInformation AuthenticationInfo, String QueryRestriction, Boolean IsRestrictedLocation, StringCollection AllowedSiteCollectionUrls, String KindsOfResults, Boolean IsPrefixPattern, String QueryReformatPattern, IList`1 SupportedLanguages, String Author, Version Version, Boolean IsDeletable, SqlSession Session) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.LocationFactory.AddLocationConfiguration(LocationConfigurationCollection LocationCollection, String InternalName, String DisplayName, String AdminDescription, LocationType Type, String ConnectionUrlTemplate, String MoreLinkTemplate, Visualization SummaryVisualization, Visualization FullVisualization, Visualization TopAnswerVisualization, AuthenticationInformation AuthenticationInfo, Boolean IsDeletable, SqlSession Session) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.LocationFactory.CreateLiveLocation(LocationConfigurationCollection LocationCollection, Boolean ShouldLog, SPLog Logger, SqlSession Session) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.LocationFactory.CreateOOBLocations(SearchServiceApplication SearchApp, Boolean ShouldLog, SPLog Logger, SqlSession Session) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Provision() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.b__22() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchAdminUtils.UpdateIgnoreSPUpdatedConcurrencyException(String description, SearchAdminUtilsUpdateDelegate updateDelegate, SearchAdminUtilsRefreshObjectDelegate refreshObjectDelegate) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.CreateSearchApp() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.ProvisionSearchServiceApplication() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigurationJobDefinition.ExecuteTimerJob()
8/7/2014 3:03:35 PM
```

I found various blogs and technet posts providing me with a variety of possible explanations and solutions.  None of which are applicable.

My Central Admin app pool is using the farm account,
   I am not using a trial license,
   The Trial license health alert is disabled,
   I successfully ran the config wizard again,
   No antivirus

I'm not sure what went wrong or when.  I'm about to start the farm over, but I wanted to see if anyone had any additional insight into this.

Comment: I am having the same scenario. Exact the same. Do you resolve this problem? Thanks

Comment: I ended up starting with a new server and re-installing SharePoint successfully..  never found the cause